# Is there a way to change just the length of sentences / formulas?

Tags: math-mode, height

I've made a document, but I've got a problem:
Some formulas made out of fractions and roots look really small on the pdf-file. The formula is right, but the height of it makes some things almost unreadable. like:

```
$\sqrt{5 + \frac{(\frac{360}{\beta} \cdot \sin \beta) - \beta}{180-\beta}}$
```

So i just want the height of some formulas to change, not the whole text?
Somebody knows how?

Comment: Perhaps inserting `\displaystyle` at the start of your formula would suffice. However, note that this will increase the height/depth dramatically when dealing with (nested) fractions, causing other text to be displaced.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Rule of thumb that I follow: if it is too much to fit inline, it deserves to be set in a `display` environment such as `\[...\]`.  If that isn't an option, have you considered `\sfrac` (as provided by the `xfrac` package), or perhaps exponent notation?

Answer (score 2):

Exemplary solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\sqrt{5 + \frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{360}{\beta} \cdot \sin \beta\right) - \beta}{180-\beta}}
\]

$\sqrt{5 + ((({360}/{\beta} )\cdot \sin \beta) - \beta)/(180-\beta)}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first version is so high, that should rather be in a displayed equation. Preferable in text is something like the second solution, however it is long and not easy to read.